# Is it possible to bulk delete Contact Notes?

Tags: contacts

I have around 500 Contact records with notes I would like to delete. Is it possible to do this in bulk?

Comment: Could you clarify if you would like to delet the contacts including the notes? Or only the notes of certain contacts?

Comment: I would like to delete the notes only. Using SearchKit seems to do the trick though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via SearchKit -

- Create new search
- Select 'Notes' in the search for box

That brings up all notes you have in the system and you can then select all and hit 'Delete' in the action menu.

If you are trying to apply any other filter criteria it can be narrowed down but we would need a little more detail.